# A small map take so much place and time?

Tags: google-maps, tilemill

I am using TileMill and try to generate an MBTile from Lyon in France.
Doing so takes me +100GB and an incalculable time (25mb for a really small portion of Lyon take me 1h)

If that is normal, does that mean services like Google Map store thousands of terabytes of images ?

Comment: One square kilometer with 1 meter pixel size makes 1 million pixels as a raster image. If image is RGB color image multiply by 3 and you get 3 MB per square kilometer as uncompressed. Compression can save disk space 40-95% depending on compression method and source data. Overviews/pyramid layers add 30% extra space. If native resolution is 0.5 meters multiply by 4. Take a calculator, area of Lyon, smallest pixel size, compression method and you can rather well estimate if +100GB is normal.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to know how tile map providers store there data or why yours is so huge and how to fix that? I would guess you either did not specify the right extends, used a too high zoom level or both.

Comment: It was just to be sure I was not going the wrong direction. Thanks for your clarifications within comments!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.